# Homemorphisms to the upper plane

Tags: general-topology

Let us consider the topological space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2$ is a group of two transformations having $\theta(x,y):=(y,x)$ as generator.
How can I write explicitely the homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+$?

Intuitively, $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}_2$ is the half plane above the line $y=x$.But I want to use, if possible, the universal property of quotient to determine the wanted homeomorphism.

My idea is the following: after denoting by $Y$ the aforementioned half plane, we can define the surjective map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to Y$, where $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ if $(x,y) \in Y$ and $f(x,y)=(y,x)$ if $(x,y) \in Y^c$ and, by the universal property of quotient, this factorizes to a homeomorphism $\overline{f}: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}_2 \to Y$. Now, with a clockwise rotation of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ (that is another homeomorphism), we arrive to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Your scheme works. Alternatively, you could use coordinates
$$
u = x + y,\quad v = x - y
$$
on $\Reals^{2}$, then send $(u, v) \in \Reals^{2}$ to $(u, |v|) \in \Reals \times \Reals_{+}$.